# Google Deployment Manager API - Updating yaml properties dynamically while creating the VM

Tags: node.js, google-api, google-cloud-platform, google-api-nodejs-client, google-deployment-manager

We are using Deployment Manager API to create VMs in our NodeJS application.

```
config.deploymentConfiguration.target.config.content = fs.readFileSync(yamlFile,config.encoding);  
var request = {
    project: config.projectId,
    resource: config.deploymentConfiguration
};
```

Here, I want to dynamically update the yaml properties before calling the create VM code.

```
deploymentManager.deployments.insert(request, function(err, response){..});
```

Please suggest the best way to do this.

Comment: lease edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: You might need to check [this](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/reference/latest/deployments/insert#code-sample) help center article as well. More information on updating a 'Deployment' can be found [here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/deployments/updating-deployments). I hope this helps you